# Excel not formatting dates on csv file

Tags: python, excel, analytics

I have been trying to perform data analysis on gold and usd data from Yahoo and the dates simply won't format I've tried everything from datevalue to TEXT(...,yyyy-mm-dd) nothing seems to be helping even chat gpt is useless here any help ill appreciate

I tried the datevalue formula which only brings up the *Value! Answer as well as the TEXT formula even trying to edit the cells either with text to columns or assigning the date values I want to the cell but the date remains unchanged

Comment: You likely have text-that-looks-like-a-date. Please provide a sample of it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first import pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
```

Then read the .csv file:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

Convert it to datetime with `pd.to_datetime()`:

```py
data['write here'] = pd.to_datetime(data['write here'])
```

And then make a new column as formatted_date:

```py
df['Formatted_Date'] = df['write here'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Good luck!

Comment: Also, @BigBen is right that you didn't provide any samples, so please be aware.